# How can I use a dialog (resource file) on a new VS 2013 project from a different VS 2013 project?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, mfc, dialog, resource-files

Let me first say that I do not want a copy of a resource file on two projects (I have seen a question about that).

Using Windows 7, MS VS 2013, C++, MFC.

These two projects I will be referencing are part of the same solution.

I have a dialog that has been created with rc/h/cpp files for it that works in one project (Project A). I want to be able to open that dialog from a routine in a separate project (Project B). Project B has a GUI button that when clicked I wish for the dialog from Project A to be brought up.

I have included a reference to Project A in the properties of Project B.

I have included (#include) the rc file path for Project A in the rc file for Project B (which takes care of the resource file, and the definition numbers for the resource file do not overlap).

I have included the path (From Project A) to the class that controls the dialog in Project B (in the file that contains the event handler to bring up the dialog).

There are no errors with the setup I have, it just doesn't do anything. I create the dialog and try a `DoModal` on it like I would anywhere in Project A (where it works) and nothing happens, I can click the button many times and it never brings anything up.

I cannot provide any of the code on this, but I hope that is enough information to give me some kind of clue. I am lost as of now. Thank you.

Ex of routine:

```
#include "DialogIWant.h"

...

void OnPushButtonOnProjectB ()
{
    CDialogIWant dialog;  // CPP/H/RC in the other project A
    dialog.DoModal();  // Nothing comes up
}
```

Comment: Project A and Project B are not automatically linked to each other. I am not sure if I follow but the way you are describing things project B should not even build successfully. If you have multiple projects in the same solution then right-click on project B, click on "*Set as startup project*" in popup menu. Put a break point on `dialog.DoModal()` and run with debugger.

Comment: Yes the Project B is the startup project, I neglected to say that. The problem is the dialog itself is null when I create it, I don't think the DoModal part is really the issue. I don't think I can even create any instance of the CDialogIWant class even though it is referenced through an #include. I basically want to know if it is possible to use a single dialog from one project in different projects and if so how do I do it. Thanks.

Comment: Is the resource actually contained withing the Project B binary, or only in Project A?  It won't be able to load the dialog if it can't locate the resource for it.  You can also try putting a breakpoint after the DoModal call to see what the return value is.  -1 means it couldn't create the dialog, IDABORT will display error information from GetLastError in the output window.

Answer (score 0):

Resource files are able to use `#inclde` the same as any other C++ file. Have the dialog resource in a separate file, and include it in the `.rc` files of both projects.

You will also need to share the resource ID definitions, which are usually in `resource.h`.